# How does Spotify's online service stream music so it's not downloadable

Tags: html, streaming, html5-audio, spotify

I'm developing a site that will host a few songs. I know in most cases music streams can be downloaded through Chrome's Developer Tools, Firebug, or the like. Soundcloud is an example site for which this method of downloading streams is possible.

On the other hand, it seem Spotify has found a way to stream music so it can't be downloaded. **How is this possible and how might one implement this level of protection for their own site?**

---

The answer and the information I was intending to gather is a hidden among all the noise of comments.

As suggested by [@idbebhold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192881/how-does-spotifys-online-service-stream-music-so-its-not-downloadable#comment-25088411), Ii turns out **RTMP streaming** is probably the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spotify isn't using HTML5 Audio. They're most likely using Flash to serve up the audio.

---

#### Edit: Spotify is using Flash for audio playback.

Upon looking at the Network tab in Chrome DevTools, [it appears that I was correct](http://cl.ly/PpWm).

To verify this I disabled the Flash plugin in Chrome (chrome://plugins/) and tried accessing Spotify. It popped up this notification: ["**To enjoy Spotify, please install Adobe Flash. It's free.**"](http://cl.ly/PpJq)

Comment: Should you then be able to see the `.flv` or `.swf` stream in Developer Tools?

Comment: No, you won't see the stream in your Network tab. Also: don't try to steal music from Spotify.

Comment: I'm not. I'm try to figure out how I can add this level of protection to a client's site.

Comment: Nope, flash isn't being used. Add flashblock to your browser and go to the web player, you'll find it works fine.

Comment: @NikReiman First, I never said they weren't serving up the audio using something else. I said "They're most likely using Flash" and looking at the Network tab in Chrome DevTools, **[it appears that I was correct](http://cl.ly/PpWm)**. Obviously they might have some fallback incase Flash isn't available (maybe the Web Audio API).

Comment: @NikReiman I disabled the Flash plugin in Chrome (chrome://plugins/) and tried accessing Spotify but it [popped up this notification: "**To enjoy Spotify, please install Adobe Flash. It's free.**"](http://cl.ly/PpJq)

Comment: Okay. Although, I thought flash would protect the actual audio content. I guess I need to acquire more knowledge of flash.

Comment: It is, kind of. It's likely using [RTMP](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28854/using-rtmp-streaming/) to stream the audio.

Comment: Great! This is the information I was looking for. Much thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just tested using tcpdump. Connections for audio are over server port 1935, which is the **RTMP** port. Browser commonly use rtmp via Flash. Indeed if you disable Flash in your browser you will not be able to use Spotify. 
Moreover, I can see they use **Cloudfront**, then I guess this service in particular: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-rtmp.html